# Generic Interfaces and heritage

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface

Here is my problem.

I've got these 3 interfaces :

```
IOperationInfoBase

IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of T As IOperationInfoBase)

IMetalUnitInfo(Of T As IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of IOperationInfoBase))
```

And another that inherits from IOperationInfoBase :

```
Public Interface IOperationInfo
  Inherits IOperationInfoBase
```

And then these 2 classes :

```
Public Class DaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo
Implements IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of IOperationInfo)

Public Class MetalUnitInfo
Implements IMetalUnitInfo(Of DaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo)
```

This first thing is right :

```
Public Property PlateName() As String Implements IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of IOperationInfo).DaughterPlateName
```

But this doesn't work :

```
Public Property MetalUnitName() As String Implements IMetalUnitInfo(Of DaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo).MetalUnitName
```

I'm stuck on the following error :

> Type argument 'DaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of IOperationInfoBase)

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Can you include the declarations of the relevant members as well?

Comment: @jmcilhinney For the problem case, a simple string property in `IMetalUnitInfo` will show the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint on `IMetalUnitInfo` requires `T` to be `IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of IOperationInfoBase)`, but you're providing it `IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of IOperationInfo)`.

Generic covariance is designed to address this.  You need to make a change to `IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo`.

```
Interface IDaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo(Of Out T As IOperationInfoBase)
```

Then, `DaughterPlateOfMetalUnitInfo` can satisfy the constraint because `IOperationInfo` is more derived than `IOperationInfoBase`.